# How to avoid remove item from second list affects the original list in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablelist

What I am trying to do is keep an original list and two duplicated ones in which to perform operations. Say `orginalList` is a list of String and has 5 entries

```
duplicatedList = originalList
secondDuplicatedList = orignalList
duplicatedList.remove(0)
secondDuplicatedList.remove(1)
```

The values are removed from all three lists and at the end all three lists will have 3 entries.

I have seen a lot of similar questions, but I do not quite get it

Any help or suggestion would be great. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `duplicatedList = originalList`

Using equal sign will make another pointer to the same location in memory (duplicatedList is not instantiated from scratch); so both `duplicatedList` & `originalList` points to the same list

Instead, you need to create a brand new list in memory with the same values of the original list.

You can use the Collection's extension function [`toMutableList()`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/34e57a45f2d4283be572137b4b497414b8833ee7/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L1332) to do that:

```
duplicatedList = originalList.toMutableList()
secondDuplicatedList = originalList.toMutableList()
```

This extension function originally creates a new list:

```
public fun <T> Collection<T>.toMutableList(): MutableList<T> {
    return ArrayList(this)
}
```

Comment: To be a little pedantic...the "equality" operator is `==`. A single equals sign is the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

try

duplicatedList.addAll(originalList)